# Recommended NameIdFormat for using User Principle Name (UPN) as NameId in SAML

Tags: azure, saml, saml-2.0, upn

We have the following name id formats to choose from.

- unspecified
- emailAddress
- X509SubjectName
- WindowsDomainQualifiedName
- kerberos
- entity
- persistent
- transient

If I need the UPN value of an user to be returned by my IDP (say Azure or ADFS, etc) which nameid format should I choose? Should I configure my IDP to send the UPN value with 'unspecified' as the nameid format or should I go choose persistent? Or is there any other recommended nameid format for sending/requesting UPN?

Comment: You must not use `transient` as it would violate the SAML spec when you populate it with a non-opaque value. However most SP implementations do not perform data validation for the value of the NameId (potentially because it's not specified in the processing rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that as the SP, you *generally* define the contract that is required to utilize your service. There's rarely a reason to **not** use unspecified, unless your federation tool supports some automated validation of the attribute against the format definition.

Even if your tool **does** support that validation, that doesn't absolve of doing your own validation of the data.

As such, I would choose unspecified. It offers the most flexibility.